# heroku & devise user sign up registration controller error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, super, railscasts

I just switched to Devise/Omniauth combo and everything is working properly on my localhost server.  However when I uploaded to heroku the app crashes when the user clicks sign up on the traditional sign up form (not omniauth login).  I am using rails 3.  My logs say

> LoadError (no such file to load --bcrypt):
>   app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:11 in 'build_resource'
>   app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:4 in create'

The referenced controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
  end

  private

  def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
      @user.valid?
    end
  end 
end
```

Line 4 and 11 are the super since the registration controller is overriding Devise.  What's going wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

in your Gemfile. If not, add it and run

```
bundle install
```

Also, you may have to delete your Gemfile.lock and try to push to Heroku again.

Comment: Thank you.  It did require deleting Gemfile.lock to get it to install, but it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running the Omniauth railscast on heroku.

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

Did the trick and no need to delete Gemfile.lock.
I also needed:

```
heroku stack:migrate bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```